# GAE app not recognized domain for signing in

Tags: google-app-engine, google-oauth

I have a number of GAE-Standard Environment "Internal" Apps which use the javascript login. I've gone in and created the client_id and entered the domain as the javascript source for a new one, but it balks... [image: screen shot of the balking]

Answer (score 0):

In order to resolve the redirect URI mismatch error with Javascript origin, you need to go to [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) and create an OAuth Client ID and set the redirect URI. Assuming that you haven't created an OAuth Client Id yet, see below steps on how to create it.

> 1. Open the Google Cloud Console
> 2. At the top-left, click Menu > APIs & Services > Credentials
> 3. Click Credentials > OAuth Client ID
> 4. Click Application type > Web application
> 5. In the "Name" field, type a name for the credential. This name is only shown in the Cloud Console.
> 6. Add authorized URIs related to your app:
>
>    - Client-side apps (JavaScript) – Under Authorized JavaScript origins, click Add URI. Then, enter a URI to use for browser requests. This identifies the domains from which your application can send API requests to the OAuth 2.0 server.
>    - Server-side apps (Java, Python, .NET, and more) – Under "Authorized redirect URIs," click Add URI. Then, enter an endpoint URI to which the OAuth 2.0 server can send responses.
> 7. Click Create. The OAuth client created screen appears, showing your new Client ID and Client secret.
> 8. Note the Client ID. Client secrets aren't used for Web applications.
> 9. Click OK. The newly created credential appears under "OAuth 2.0 Client IDs."
> 10. Optional: If you're creating credentials as a prerequisite for a JavaScript quickstart, you must also generate an API key.

[image]

On the other hand, if you already have an existing OAuth Client ID, on your OAuth 2.0 Client IDs Dashboard, click on `Edit OAuth Client`. Now, under `Authorized Javascript Origins` and `Authorized redirect URLs` add the redirect url,  i.e `https://tamarackcId.appspot.com`, then save it. Try to login again after a few minutes.

**Note:** Updating the Google API console and for the change to reflect can take some time. Redirect URIs are also case-sensitive and trailing-slash sensitive.

You can also refer to this [OAuth client ID credentials](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#oauth-client-id) guide.